# Array elements out of index in C

Tags: c

**Declaration for an array in C is:**

type name [elements];

So why doesn't this code throw an exception such as "out of bounds" or any other exception?

```
#include <stdio.h>
void main()
{
    int a[5];
    a[7]=75;
    printf("%d",a[7]); 
}
```

Comment: because there is no such exception. You can do wrong things and bad things will happen. Its you who has to make sure that your code is correct

Comment: read about undefined behaviour. There is a huge list of stuff you can do wrong and the compilers are allowed to emit no error or warning but just silently do anything

Comment: it is going to store that value in memory directly after your defined array. 
If something else is using whatever is defined after it could get ugly.

Comment: This a good explanation about array length and bounds checking in C: https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/237290

Comment: @FBergo I wouldnt claim that `std::vector` was introduced to make c++ more "idiots friendly" ;)

Comment: the code is almost a duplicate of [Out of index C/C++](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26364095/995714)

Comment: C does not require any bounds checking on array accesses, so as long as you don't do anything that causes the memory manager or operating system to complain (like cross a page boundary or something), you won't get any kind of run-time error.  If you write to something outside of the array bounds, you may get a run-time error later, depending on what you overwrote.

Answer (score 0):

Because in C the variable with the name of the array is the pointer to the first memory-cell of the array and the number between brackets is the offset of the data you want from the starting of the array, it doesn't check if it is a memory cell of the array or not.

Comment: Arrays are not pointers and this confusion needs to cease.

Comment: I didn't say it...

Comment: Actually, it *is* the pointer to the first (technically 0th index) element of the array. That is why calling `*p` works, pointer arithmetic etc

Comment: @EpicPandaForce: An array is not a pointer and a pointer is no array. Just like Quentin said: thi confusion needs to cease! [conv.array]/1: An lvalue or rvalue of type “array of N T” or “array of unknown bound of T” *can be converted* to a prvalue of type “pointer to T”. The temporary materialization conversion ([conv.rval]) is applied. The result is a pointer to the first element of the array.

Comment: Oh, the question is tagged "C" ... well. [6.3.2.1 Lvalues, arrays, and function designators]/3: Except when it is the operand of the sizeof operator, the _Alignof operator, or the unary & operator, or is a string literal used to initialize an array, an expression that has type ''array of type'' *is converted to an expression with type ''pointer to type''* that points to the initial element of the array object and is not an lvalue. If the array object has register storage class, the behavior is undefined.